# To move or sort internal using jquery drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have following code for jquery drag and drop. I've nested drag and drop functionality.

http://jsfiddle.net/bhumi/nkvzdwk9/10/

It is not working when try to move dropped item internally?

I have tried to change connectWith with following line

```
connectWith: \".ui-sortable\",
```

See below image

[image]

But not working. please help.

Comment: very hard to understand what you want. Much detail but none specific. Sort and drag and more drag but each of these points needs a heavy amount of detail.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich: If you check demo it is too easy to understand. I just want to allow to move dropped content in area where as right now when i'm trying to move,content is removed.

Comment: @BhumiShah, I think there is problem with reference, Try to debug it.

Comment: @HP's411: Can you please provide solution. I am not getting what do you mean by reference?

Comment: @BhumiShah : I mean to say that when your drop an Item to Layout, you are providing an ID to it, at the time you change its position from Layout to Your List it disappears from it. so i think that there is some problem with ID's your are providing to content. Lets see what i can do. I am trying to solve it.

Comment: @BhumiShah : what i got is, When You are moving an Item from a List to another list, it throws an Error `ReferenceError: disp is not defined`.
I think you shoud use `FIREBUG` tool and try to solve these Errors.
Thanks..!!!

Comment: @HP's411: please check updated fiddle,disp is not neccessory to use.

Comment: your fiddle link does not link to a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked the HTML in the Fiddle, and I found that if we move the **List2** out of **workarea** then it is working.

Please check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nkvzdwk9/13/)

```
<div class="workarea" style="border: 1px solid green; width: 30%; padding: 0; margin: 0 0 0 15px; float: left">
<h3>Your List</h3></div><ul id="list2" class="connectedSortable ui-sortable" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100%; height: 500px"></ul>
```

Comment: I want to allow to move dropped content from drop-container to list2 and vice versa

Comment: I mean i want to move dropped contain in drop-container to list2

Answer (score 0):

Check this...i modified your code a little...you can now drop items like you described in your image.

```
$(function () {
    //Radix: Added layout list
    $("#list3 li").draggable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
        console.log('started dragging layout')
        },
        connectToSortable: "#list2",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        stop:function(){
        }
    });

    //Radix End
        $("#list1 li").draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#list2 .drop-container,#list2",
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid",
            greedy: true
        });

        $("#list2").sortable({
            connectWith: "#list1",
            over: function () {
                removeIntent = false;
                $(this).css("background-color", "green");
            },
            out: function () {
                removeIntent = true;
                $(this).css("background-color", "orange");
            },
            beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
                itemContext = ui.item.context;
                if (removeIntent == true) {
                    ui.item.remove();
                    //disp($("#list2").sortable('toArray'));
                }
                //console.log(itemContext);

            },
            receive: function (event, ui) {
                console.log(ui);
                console.log(event);
                var this_id = $(ui.item).attr("id");
                var preview = $(itemContext).html().replace(/<!--/g, '').replace(/-->/g, '');

                $(itemContext).attr("id", this_id);
               $(itemContext).css("width", '530px').addClass("ui-state-default").height('auto');
                $(itemContext).html(preview);

                $("#list2 .drop-container").sortable({
                    connectWith: ".drop-container",
                    over: function () {
                        removeIntent = false;
                        $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
                    },
                    out: function () {
                        removeIntent = true;
                        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
                    },
                    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
                        itemContext = ui.item.context;
                        if (removeIntent == true) {
                            //ui.item.remove();
                            //disp($("#list2").sortable('toArray'));
                        }
                        //console.log(itemContext);

                    }

                }); //.disableSelection()
            }       
        }); //.disableSelection()

     $("#list2").bind("sortupdate", function (event, ui) {
        //console.log($('#list2'));
        var result = $('#list2').sortable('toArray');
        var str='';
        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                str+=result[i]+"|";
                var tmp="#"+result[i]+" .drop-container";
            if($(tmp).length>0){
                $(tmp).each(function(){
                    if($(this).children("li").length){
                        str+=$(this).parent()[0].id+"|";
                        $(this).children("li").each(function(){
                            str+=this.id+"|";

                        })
                    }
                })
            } 
        }       //console.log(result);
        //alert(str);
    });
});
```

```css
#list1, #list2, #list3 {
    border:1px solid red;
}
#list1, #list2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    background-color:grey;
}
#list1 li, #list2 li, #list3 li {
    margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 2px;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    width: 480px;
    cursor: move;
}
#list2 li {
    margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    width: 744px;
    cursor: move;
    /*height:22px;*/
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table id='list3' class='display compact' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='color:#000000;'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <li id="Layout1">
                    <!--<span><a href="../../test.php?src=&w=700" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Preview</button></a></span>&nbsp;--><span>Layout1</span>
                    <!--<span style="float:right;"><input type='text' name='time1[]'  value='10' class='input-layout' style='width: 35%;float:right' maxlength='4' onKeyup="return checkIt(this)" ></span>  <ul><li id="25">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddMediaModel" data-pid="0">Add Media</button>Left<ul class="drop-container" style="min-height: 100px;border:1px solid red"></ul></li><li id="26">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddMediaModel" data-pid="0">Add Media</button>Right<ul class="drop-container" style="min-height: 100px;border:1px solid red"></ul></li><li id="27">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddMediaModel" data-pid="0">Add Media</button>Front<ul class="drop-container" style="min-height: 100px;border:1px solid red"></ul></li></ul>-->
                </li>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <li id="Layout2">
                    <!--<span><a href="../../test.php?src=&w=700" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Preview</button></a></span>&nbsp;--><span>Layout2</span>
                    <!--<span style="float:right;"><input type='text' name='time1[]'  value='10' class='input-layout' style='width: 35%;float:right' maxlength='4' onKeyup="return checkIt(this)" ></span>  <ul><li id="29">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddMediaModel" data-pid="0">Add Media</button>Left<ul class="drop-container" style="min-height: 100px;border:1px solid red"></ul></li><li id="30">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddMediaModel" data-pid="0">Add Media</button>Right<ul class="drop-container" style="min-height: 100px;border:1px solid red"></ul></li><li id="31">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddMediaModel" data-pid="0">Add Media</button>asd<ul class="drop-container" style="min-height: 100px;border:1px solid red"></ul></li></ul>-->
                </li>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <li id="Layout3">
                    <!--<span><a href="../../test.php?src=&w=700" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Preview</button></a></span>&nbsp;--><span>Layout3</span>
                    <!--<span style="float:right;"><input type='text' name='time1[]'  value='10' class='input-layout' style='width: 35%;float:right' maxlength='4' onKeyup="return checkIt(this)" ></span>  <ul><li id="28">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddMediaModel" data-pid="0">Add Media</button>New<ul class="drop-container" style="min-height: 100px;border:1px solid red"></ul></li></ul>-->
                </li>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/>

<h3>Media</h3>

<table id='list1' class='display compact' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='color:#000000;' ;>
    <thead>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Upload Time</th>
        <th>Preview</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <li id="test.jpg">
                    <!--<span><a href="../../test.php?src=// test.jpg&w=700" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Preview</button></a></span>&nbsp;-->test.jpg
                    <!--<span style="float:right;"><input type='text'  name='time1[]'  value='10' class='input-layout' style='width: 35%;float:right'  maxlength='4' onKeyup="return checkIt(this)" ></span>-->
                </li>
            </td>
            </td>
            <td>Test media</td>
            <td>11-Mar-15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <li id="test.jpg">
                    <!--<span><a href="../../test.php?src=/test.jpg&w=700" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Preview</button></a></span>&nbsp;-->test.jpg
                    <!--<span style="float:right;"><input type='text'  name='time1[]'  value='10' class='input-layout' style='width: 35%;float:right'  maxlength='4' onKeyup="return checkIt(this)" ></span>-->
                </li>
            </td>
            </td>
            <td>Test media</td>
            <td>26-Mar-15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <li id="testimg.jpg">
                    <!--<span><a href="../../test.php?src=/testimg.jpg&w=700" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Preview</button></a></span>&nbsp;-->testimg.jpg
                    <!--<span style="float:right;"><input type='text'  name='time1[]'  value='10' class='input-layout' style='width: 35%;float:right'  maxlength='4' onKeyup="return checkIt(this)" ></span>-->
                </li>
            </td>
            </td>
            <td>Test media</td>
            <td>26-Mar-15</td>
            <td><a href="../../test.php?src=/testimg.jpg&w=700" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Preview</button></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <li id="testimg1.jpg">
                    <!--<span><a href="../../test.php?src=//testimg1.jpg&w=700" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Preview</button></a></span>&nbsp;-->testimg1.jpg
                    <!--<span style="float:right;"><input type='text'  name='time1[]'  value='10' class='input-layout' style='width: 35%;float:right'  maxlength='4' onKeyup="return checkIt(this)" ></span>-->
                </li>
            </td>
            </td>
            <td>Test media</td>
            <td>25-Mar-15</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="workarea" style="border:1px solid green; width:45%; padding:0; margin:0 0 0 15px;float:left">

<h3>Your List</h3>

    <ul id="list2" class="connectedSortable ui-sortable" style="border:1px solid red; width:100%;height:500px"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using JQuery UI Sortable like [this example](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists).

Also, try building off [this basic working example (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/fzgoLxr4/3/).

HTML:

```
<h3>Name</h3>
<ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Layout 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Layout 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Layout 3</li>
</ul>

<h3>Media</h3>
<ul id="sortable2" class="droptrue">
    <li class="ui-state-default">test.jpg</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">test.jpg</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">testimg.jpg</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">testimg.jpg1</li>
</ul>

<h3>Your List</h3>
<ul id="sortable3" class="droptrue">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Drop here</li>
</ul>

<br style="clear:both" />
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul"
    });

    $("ul.dropfalse").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul",
        dropOnEmpty: false
    });

    $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3").disableSelection();
});
```

CSS:

```
#sortable1,
#sortable2,
#sortable3 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 143px;
}
#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li,
#sortable3 li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: This is basic example,not a nested level. if you can create demo as i require then i will be useful to me

Answer (score 0):

You have to make exact connection between element inside particular events since there is a lot of dragging and dropping of elements between different parents

You need to call draggable on `*.jpg` when they come inside #list2 on all the receive events

```
$("#list2").find("#test\\.jpg,#testimg\\.jpg,#testimg1\\.jpg").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#list2 .drop-container,#list2",
    revert: "invalid",
    stop:function(){
    }
});
```

And then use the `connectWith` option properly

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ankit2038/nw879v9a/show/)